# How do unexpected speed fluctuations in Scrapy relate to throttling?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, throttling

I am running a scraper that crawls about 25 domains with in total about 100k pages. The speed in the beginning is about 500 pages per minute, but it slows down considerably afterwards to about one hundred pages per minute. My reasoning was that this could be due to the throttling that I enabled in the settings.py file. Yet, after running the spider for five hours, I noticed that the speed went even down to about 5 pages per minute.

My initial understanding was that the spider would probably be stuck at one domain that was slow in responding. However, this understanding didn't make sense anymore when I spotted some huge fluctuations in the scraping speed. After being stuck for hours in the range 0-20 pages per minute, occasionally there is a speed up to 100-500 pages per minute(mosttimes for only one or two minutes). How could the latter speedups be explained considering that a domain would be slowing down in its responses to me?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial understanding is probably correct - sound like you are getting temporarily throttled which results in fluctuating speeds.